# remove non english word smarty

Tags: php, html, encoding, smarty

I am currently working with smarty 2.6. I get data from the database (I don't have access, I just fetch the data) as `&#225;` in a string.

I need to change it to **`á`** in the `.csv` file that I am making.

I tried `{$string|html_entity_decode}`, but is not working.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: does {'&#225;'|html_entity_decode} work? can you show us a fragment of your template?

Comment: It does not work.

>> Assigning variable from array[$Trip] obtained form database 
{{assign var="train_name" value=$Trip.TrainName}}

>> Used to create csv
  ,"{{$train_name|html_entity_decode}}"

Comment: when you say that it does not work, you mean that it just outputs &#225; or a wrong character?

Comment: its giving away &#225;

Comment: Which PHP version do you use?

Comment: PHP 4 is the version that am using.

Comment: I read at php.net that it seems that html_entity_decode does not decode numeric entity references in PHP 4.x. You could use this function from the comments as a workaround http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.html-entity-decode.php#51055 . Wrap this in a smarty plugin, will fit your needs. I also recommend to check the other comments on http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.html-entity-decode.php

Comment: Encoding/decoding (or escaping for that matter) is not the same as encryption, so please don't use [tag:encryption] for that.

Comment: Thanks you guys for your inputs.
@owlstead Will take care of it mate.. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help.

made a change in modifier and got it done.

FYI,code that was altered.

```
  $char_set="ISO-8859-1";

  if (function_exists('mb_split')) {
    return mb_convert_encoding($string ,  $char_set , 'HTML-ENTITIES');
  }
  else {
    return html_entity_decode($string , ENT_NOQUOTES . $char_set);
  }
```

This works.